# I do not see disks while building a Scale-Out File Server on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

Following are my environment details

- I have created 2 virtual machines in Azure. **node 01** and **node 02**
- Both machines are using windows server 2012 R2
- Attached disks for node 01 and node 02
- Added node 01 and 02 to **fail over cluster**

Then I went to following area in Fail over cluster manager to add **new** Disks

> Failover Cluster Manager -> Storage -> Disks

But, I do not see any disks as shown below

[image]

When I try to add disks, I am getting below error message

[image]

**Why I need disks?**

I am trying to create file share access using **scale out file server feature**

I do not see drives in **New Share Wizard** as shown below

[image]

I do understand that once the cluster setup is done we need to add disks to shared volume using "add to cluster shared volume” option
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/12/11/scale-out-file-shares-and-continuously-available-file-services.aspx but I do not see any disks!

**Update**
One of friend suggested as follow

> To deploy Windows Server Failover Clusters on Microsoft Azure VMs, you would need third-party storage-level replication software like **StarWind Virtual SAN** or **SIOS Data Keeper.**

But I am not sure will these third party support all my production requirements.

Steps to configure SQL AlwaysOn FCI in Azure IaaS Cloud with StarWind Virtual SAN Solution 
http://www.tech-coffee.net/sql-alwayson-fci-in-azure-iaas-cloud-with-starwind-virtual-san-solution/

Comment: cluster manager needs the disk to be offline not online connected to one of the hosts

Comment: Do I need to add disk on both the nodes?

Comment: as far as I remember it's just attached to any host but not online

Comment: Ok, let me add disk to node 01 and node 02 from azure portal and let me keep it offline. will keep you posted.

Comment: Mentioned StarWind VSAN is available directly in Azure. FYI. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/starwind/starwindvirtualsan/

Comment: Yes, you need HA shared storage for proper production setup. Here are two deployment guides that will be helpful to you: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/installing-and-configuring-a-sql-server-fci-on-microsoft-azure-vms - for Azure specific setup. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/installing-and-configuring-a-sql-server-2012-failover-cluster - for general SQL FCI deployment.

Comment: And here is also a great video to better understand the whole concept: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/save-10kon-sql-deployment-in-microsoft-azure P.S: srry for doubleposting

Comment: Does Microsoft and Azure have tie up? so I have to pay for both the vendors!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to connect shared disk on both nodes. Then you must configure and format share volume on one of the 2 nodes : this should be performed only on first of the File Server VM, not both. On the first node, initialize the iSCSI LUN

The following link is a very complete step by step guide "Deploying a Windows Server 2012 R2 Scale-Out File Server Cluster using Azure VMs" that you should have a look to : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/03/29/deploying-a-windows-server-2012-r2-scale-out-file-server-cluster-using-azure-vms/

Just to be sure that you are using a supported configuration for the storage. Do you have the following prerequisites ?

Microsoft server software support for Microsoft Azure virtual machines
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2721672

Requirements for Windows Server Failover Cluster with Azure Iaas VM :
Must Run Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2
For Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2008 R2, must have hotfix 2854082 installed on all nodes. Must use a single-cluster IP address resource. 
Must use Azure-hosted storage by using one of the following options:
        Application-level replication for nonshared storage | 
        Volume-level replication for nonshared storage |
        ExpressRoute for remote iSCSI Target shared block storage |
        Azure Files for shared file storage

Comment: The iSCSI Target Server configuration shown in the article is not highly available.so I can not use it in production.